# Getting flickr thumbnail

Tags: php, web-services, flickr

I'm trying to get a thumbnail of flickr pictures in PHP.

All I saw was this in their API:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

Which is a overkill. In instagr.am/twitpic and others I found a very easy way of doing so (just adding to the url the request).

Is there an option with flickr I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the URL to the Flickr image, all you have to do is modify the suffix to get a different size of the photo. For example:

`http://farm1.staticflickr.com/2/1418878_1e92283336_m.jpg`

This URL loads the medium sized photo. If we simply change the `_m` to `_t`, we would get the thumbnail:

`http://farm1.staticflickr.com/2/1418878_1e92283336_t.jpg`

You can also use `s` for small, `z` for medium, and `b` for large.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a PHP wrapper around Flickr API and keep it simple - http://phpflickr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the photo's ID out of the URL and get the thumbnail URL via [`flickr.photos.getSizes`](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html). This is likely how Twitpic/Instagram handle it.

Comment: But for that I got to have an API key and parse the url and than the XML. No way to avoid this?

Comment: You could scrape Flickr's pages, but their HTML is subject to change. API keys are free and take 30 seconds to get. You're going to have to do a little parsing of something no matter what. There are plenty of PHP Flickr libraries that'll handle the parsing for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, flickr doesn't support the simple functionality that other photo sharing services does. So the answer to my question is you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the username of the flickr user you can try to use this [small bot](http://www.barattalo.it/demo/parseflickrfeed.php). It uses the feed to retrieve the last images of the user, so it works only on the last images... I hope it will help you.